# What 3D coordinate system transformations should i do to values from a system to another one

Tags: 3d, unreal-engine4, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to change from a 3D coordinate system to another, a draw will speak better than me (sorry for the quality :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ7Ct.png)
What transform should I do from the PY values to get to UE ones ?

I tried some things i saw here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920406/transform-roll-pitch-yaw-from-one-coordinate-system-to-another but the transformation is not the same